# How do I generate a sampling distribution of a joint logistic-normal distribution in R?

Tags: normal-distribution, sampling, joint-distribution, bernoulli-distribution

I am working on a problem related to travel distances of people. I will use leisure trips (this includes day trips or multi-day trips) as an analogy. Focusing purely on the one-way travel distance, the further away the person has to travel to reach the destination, the more likely to require accommodation and stay overnight. For example, a one-way distance of 50km means a person might be entirely happy to drive there in the morning and then home again that night. This is as opposed to a one-way distance of 300km, if someone has to drive that far, they're much more likely to stay overnight at the destination, rather than drive home again.

I have data that includes the travel distance per person and whether they used accommodation (of any sort) at their destination (0/1). Realistically the distribution of the travel distances is not normal but it gives a general idea.

What I ultimately would like to be able to do is come up with a joint distribution I can sample from that gives me the probability of the person using accommodation at the destination vs the travel distance e.g. if a person travels 34km one-way, they will have a 12% chance of staying in accommodation while someone travelling 158km has am 88% probability of staying overnight in accommodation. I would like to be able to do this across the range of travel distances. If it is not possible, my backup plan is to break up the travel distances into chunks e.g. 0-10km and base accommodation probabilities on that each little segment manually.

I appreciate any and all feedback. If perhaps I have conceptualised the problem or possible solution incorrectly please let me know.

This is sample code to create a dataframe close enough to what my data looks like.

```r
if(!require("tidyr")) install.packages("tidyr")
library(tidyr)
if(!require("stringi")) install.packages("stringi")
library(stringi)

# Generate data frame
set.seed(18613)
N <- 1000


ID <- stri_rand_strings(N, 8)
dist <- abs(rnorm(n = N, mean = 5, sd = 3)); dist[501:1000] <- (dist[501:1000] * 5) + rnorm(500, mean = 112, sd = 90)
accom <- rep(NA, N)

for (i in 1:N) {
  if (i <= 250) accom[i] <- sample(c(0, 1), 1, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.95, 0.05))
  if (i <= 600) accom[i] <- sample(c(0, 1), 1, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.65, 0.35))
  else accom[i] <- sample(c(0, 1), 1, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.05, 0.95))
}

travel <- tibble(ID = ID,
                 dist = dist,
                 accom = accom)
```

Comment: It is unclear to me if you want to estimate the parameters of this joint distribution ("I have data") or pick an arbitrary distribution $p(\text{dist})\times p(\text{accom}|\text{dist})$ to simulate from.

Comment: I am ultimately trying to simulate the joint distribution so I can sample from it so I would say what I am after more aligns with your second point. I want to be able to understand how to practically simulate accurately what is happening in my data and then sample from it so the underlying theory of it is important but I want to ideally get an idea of the R code that would allow me to do that.

Comment: "how to practically simulate accurately what is happening in my data" is a very unclear sentence. Your data cannot tell what is the distribution that hypothetically generated said data.